# Raid 1 fails to mount

Tags: mount, raid, lvm, mdadm

I'm a new Ubuntu user with little experience in Linux. I setup an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS at home to recover my data from a failed Synology which I have done.

I successfully configured 2 raid drives - 
/dev/md1 - 2x4TB
/dev/md2 - 2x8TB

I have also setup LVM2 to create two logical volumes which which i made readable using "gksu nautlius" and to share them on my home network. 
However, when i rebooted Ubuntu, md1 did not mount correctly and became a raid 0 device with only /dev/sdb as the single HDD. The other HDD is /dev/sba is no longer part of /dev/md2 raid1 array. I have recreated the array twice to the same effect.

```
ajay@ajay-ubuntu:~$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME     SIZE FSTYPE            TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sdf      7.3T linux_raid_member disk  
└─md2    7.3T LVM2_member       raid1 
sdd      1.8T linux_raid_member disk  
└─md0    3.7T ext4              raid0 /mnt/md0
sdb      3.7T linux_raid_member disk  
sdi      1.8T                   disk  
└─sdi1   1.8T ntfs              part  /media/ajay/Data
sdg    115.7G                   disk  
└─sdg1 115.7G vfat              part  /media/ajay/UBUNTU
sde      7.3T linux_raid_member disk  
└─md2    7.3T LVM2_member       raid1 
sdc      1.8T linux_raid_member disk  
└─md0    3.7T ext4              raid0 /mnt/md0
sda      3.7T                   disk  
sdh    115.1G                   disk  
├─sdh3 114.1G ext4              part  /
├─sdh1    47M vfat              part  /boot/efi
└─sdh2   954M swap              part  [SWAP]
```

Here is my fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=0d3bc049-63de-44a2-8fc7-a7c45e337126 /               ext4    errors=remoun$
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=9BC4-0642  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=d8af452c-83ec-4510-8f1c-49347243547c none            swap    sw           $
/dev/md0 /mnt/md0 ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0
# /dev/md1 /mnt/md1 ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0
# /dev/md2 /mnt/md2 ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0
/dev/LVMVolGroup1/media /mnt/media ext4 defaults,nofail 0 0
/dev/LVMVolGroup1/docs /mnt/docs ext4 defaults,nofail 0 0
```

Here is my mdadm.conf

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=ajay-ubuntu:0 UUID=3fec1452:6d82d7e5:b2ea572a:$
ARRAY /dev/md2 metadata=1.2 name=ajay-ubuntu:2 UUID=39d1fe40:60274276:67049131:$
ARRAY /dev/md1 metadata=1.2 name=ajay-ubuntu:1 UUID=c07fed63:c47033a1:c1a24a04:$
```

I followed the tutorials at [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-raid-arrays-with-mdadm-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Any idea what's going on here or where i have messed up? Thank you.